# Spring @RestController Get Request Content-Type to response json or html

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

how can I take request Content-Type value? We need this to print json response or Html respone. My code is this:

```
 @RestController
public class GestorController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/gestores", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public Object gestoresHtml(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="sh14") String name) throws Exception {
        String json = "prueba json";

        String contentType = ?????

        if(contentType.equals("application/json")){
            return json;
        }else{
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("gestores");
            mav.addObject("name", name);
            return mav;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Content-Type` is a request header and you can get with the following code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/display")
    public void display(@RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType)  {}
```

see spring's `@RequestHeader` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestheader)

You don't need to do this manually. The thing that you need is `Content negotiation`. Which returns response type that will fit in your needs. See this [post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)